# can we distributed file system to images between docker daemons

Tags: image, docker

we have multi machine with docker daemons, can we share docker images between them by using distributed file system.

docker info

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -g /var/lib/docker3
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not advised. As you can read for example [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9935), you would have to share the `/var/lib/docker` folder between hosts, which is meant to work with one Docker daemon only. Sharing this == "asking for trouble".

One way to go here is setting up a [private container registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/).

Comment: it make sense to me

Comment: please consider accepting the answer if you're fine with it